# Why explode log file excluding spring-boot-starter-logging?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hikaricp

I deployed a war project in a Tomcat and it works without any problem. So I tried to deploy same war project in another tomcat. To deploy in this new Tomcat I need to insert this exclusion in my `pom.xml` file:

`spring-boot-starter-logging`

this exclusion get a lot of log lines ... inserting exclusion I have a log line every 30 seconds. This is the log line :

```
2019-10-02 11:36:08 DEBUG HikariPool:404 - ProjectHikaryPool - Pool stats (total=10, active=0, idle=10, waiting=0)
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UcQ2s.png)

Answer (score 0):

spring-boot-starter-logging is embedded in the spring boot starter web. Spring boot is not dedicated to a specific logging framework and the default one is logback as you can read in the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-logging.html). Enabeling the spring-boot-starter-logging or spring-boot-starter-web will print out all the system side debug information to the console. If you disable it the logs won't be printed. Why don't you expect this behaviour?
If you want to change the log level that is printed to the console you can use

```
logging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate=ERROR
```

for example as mentioned in the docs

Comment: I would remove some logs because excluding spring-boot-starter-logging I can see a lot of logs. Without exclude I saw some logs, the same I would. Now I have more unuseful logs lines.